# Convert character to the corresponding virtual-key code

Tags: c#, virtual, keycode

Currently, I'm using the method `VkKeyScan` in the Win32 API to convert a character to its virtual-key code. But the problem that this seems to have is that, when i pass small alphabets, it works fine whereas when i pass in a capital alphabet, it doesn't return the appropriate key code and similarly with special characters like "(" or "}".

How do i do this? Is there anyway for me to directly convert a string to its virtual equivalent without considering whether it contains capitalized or special characters?

Thanks

Comment: No you can't, the modifier keys are important, especially Shift.  And the keyboard layout, "}" requires a dead key on German keyboards (I think).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be clearer in what your requirements are, more specifically in what you consider to be an appropriate key code. The `VkKeyScan` as specified in it's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646329%28VS.85%29.aspx) returns the virtual-key code in the low-order byte and the shift state in the high-byte of the return value.

This is demonstrated in the code snippet below that uses the `'('` character as input for the `VkKeyScan` method.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]static extern short VkKeyScan(char ch);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var helper = new Helper { Value = VkKeyScan('(') };

    byte virtualKeyCode = helper.Low;
    byte shiftState = helper.High;

    Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", virtualKeyCode, (Keys)virtualKeyCode);
    Console.WriteLine("SHIFT pressed: {0}", (shiftState & 1) != 0);
    Console.WriteLine("CTRL pressed: {0}", (shiftState & 2) != 0);
    Console.WriteLine("ALT pressed: {0}", (shiftState & 4) != 0);
    Console.WriteLine();

    Keys key = (Keys)virtualKeyCode;

    key |= (shiftState & 1) != 0 ? Keys.Shift : Keys.None;
    key |= (shiftState & 2) != 0 ? Keys.Control : Keys.None;
    key |= (shiftState & 4) != 0 ? Keys.Alt : Keys.None;

    Console.WriteLine(key);
    Console.WriteLine(new KeysConverter().ConvertToString(key));
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Helper
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]public short Value;
    [FieldOffset(0)]public byte Low;
    [FieldOffset(1)]public byte High;
}
```

Running this snippet will result in the following output:

```
// 56|D8
// SHIFT pressed: True
// CTRL pressed: False
// ALT pressed: False
// 
// D8, Shift
// Shift+8
```