# ASCII character from VK_Code

Tags: c, winapi, keycode, shift

I have a small WIN32 C-Application in which i work with the [`KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure. This structure contains the VK-Code for a pressed key.

I try to convert this to an ASCII-Character. For this i use the Function [`MapVirtualKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which works well.

The only problem is, that one VK-Code can stay for multiple chars.
Example:

On my keyboard (Swiss-German) exists the key-char <kbd>.</kbd>. If i press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> then it creates a `:`. The VK-Code is the same. Thats no problem, and i can also check if <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed or <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is activated.

My only problem is: How can i get the char ':'?
I need a function like this:

`GetKeyChar(vkCode, shift)`

I need this to get the "normal" and the "shifted" value of the keyboard. Of course i could hardcode this, but i don't like to do it on this way.

Comment: Wrong function, ToUnicodeEx() required.  You'll have much bigger problems with dead keys, present on German keyboards.  Proper translation requires the keyboard state, it is a per-process property.  You can only easily get the keyboard state of your own process, not of the process that currently has the focus.  I've never seen a solution for this.

Comment: actually the keyboard state is per-thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT` doesn't have all the information you need in order to do the translation. You get a message every time a key is pressed. So for Shift+X, you'll get an input message saying that the Shift key was pressed, and another message saying that the "X" key was pressed.

You need to call [GetKeyboardState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646299%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in order to get the state of the Shift, Alt, Ctrl, (and perhaps other) keys. Then call `ToAsciiEx` or `ToUnicodeEx`.

Comment: For a keyboard hook wouldn't it be more appropriate to update a keystate array manually from the input events? (something like `BYTE k = kb.vkCode; keystate[k]&=0x80; if(!(kb.flags&LLKHF_UP)) keystate[k]|=0x80;`)

Comment: Ok, thanks. This worked, i combined GetKeyboardState with ToAsciiEx. The dead keys are not good, but it's not a big problem.

Comment: @user786653: yes, you're correct. In a hook you'd probably want to maintain your own keyboard state structure from the events rather than by calling the API.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`ToUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646320(v=VS.85).aspx), which returns the unicode character generated by that keypress.

Answer (score 2):

The functions you are looking for are: ToAscii, ToAsciiEx, ToUnicode, ToUnicodeEx.

Answer (score 0):

`short VkKeyScan(char ch)` API has contained the shift information. It translate char to virtual-key code and shift state.

See this: [Convert character to the corresponding virtual-key code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934557/convert-character-to-the-corresponding-virtual-key-code)