# How do i convert a Char to VK (Virtual-key code)

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert char key to Virtual key code, i don't really understand how to implement it. I only see bunch of help on converting VK to Char -  For example i would like to convert A to VK (0x41)

Vitual-key codes;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

i have tried looking into some websites but none explained how to doesn't seem to work. I am not good with c# yet still learning it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934557/convert-character-to-the-corresponding-virtual-key-code
I found it by googling "C# convert string to Virtual key code"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898806/how-to-convert-a-character-to-key-code